# iOSでWebRTCのDataChannelを使って大きいデータを送信すると接続が切れる

Tags: ios

iOSにおいてWebRTCのDataChannelを利用してアプリケーションデータ（画像やテキストなど）をピア間で送信しようと考えています。
数文字のテキストや10KB程度の画像データなら問題なく送受信可能なのですが、
100KB程の画像データを送信しようとするとRTCDataChannelのデリゲートメソッドchannelDidChangeStateが呼ばれ、接続が切れてしまいます。

ネイティブAPIのDataChannelを利用した例をググっても全くヒットしないのでダメ元で質問させて貰いました。何か心当たりのある方がいらしたら助言をいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: UDPのデータ長の上限を超えてるんじゃないでしょうか？WebRTCを使って大きなファイルをやりとりするアプリケーションは、一度に送信せずに細かく分割して送信するような実装になっていることが多いようです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。その辺りの分割処理はてっきりWebRTCがやってくれるものと思っていました。再度確認してみます。